# Segmentation number from water meter

Tags: java, opencv, image-segmentation, contour

i have a problem with character segmentation from water meter,
i have a image water meter

Then i have threshold this image after threshold

And i have get a register meter after segmentation

My problem is to get each character from register meter..

Here my code:

```
System.out.println("Character Segmentation the image at " + path + "... ");
// get the jpeg image from the internal resource folder
Mat image = MatImageFromPath;           

// convert the image in gray scale
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
// thresholding the image to make a binary image
Imgproc.threshold(image, image, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

// finding the contours
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

Imgproc.drawContours(image, contours, 3, new Scalar(0, 255, 0),3);

// finding best bounding rectangle for a contour whose distance is closer to the image center that other ones
Rect rect = new Rect();
ArrayList<Rect> contourRects = new ArrayList<Rect>();
Point p1 = new Point(rect.x,rect.y);
Point p2 = new Point((rect.x+rect.width),(rect.y+rect.height));
int i=0;
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);
        contourRects.add(rect);
        contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(i).toArray() );
        i++;
        }

        Collections.sort(contourRects, new Comparator<Rect>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Rect o1, Rect o2){
        return o1.x-o2.x;
        }
        });

        for (int j = 0; j <= contourRects.size()-1; j++) {
            if ((contourRects.get(j).width >= 50 && contourRects.get(j).width <= 120) && 
                                (contourRects.get(j).height >= 150 && contourRects.get(j).height <= 210)) {
                            System.out.println(contourRects.get(j).width);
                            Mat result = image.submat(contourRects.get(j));
                            Imgcodecs.imwrite("BoundingBox/"+(j+1)+".png", result);
//                           write the new image on disk
                            path = "BoundingBox/"+(j+1)+".png";
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    Imgcodecs.imwrite("BoundingBox/draw.png", image);
                    label2.setIcon(ImageFromPath(path));
```

All images at : [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm6de.jpg)

can anyone help my problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Shai thanks i have added all images

Comment: This seems a problem you could easily solve with a CNN pretrained with the MNIST dataset.  Have you tried?